# Adding a WMS layer using folium

Tags: python, dictionary, layer, folium, wms

I am using folium package in Python to construct the map in this link:
[GeoAdmin Map Link](https://map.geo.admin.ch/?lang=en&topic=ech&bgLayer=ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe&layers=ch.swisstopo.zeitreihen,ch.bfs.gebaeude_wohnungs_register,ch.bav.haltestellen-oev,ch.swisstopo.swisstlm3d-wanderwege,ch.astra.wanderland-sperrungen_umleitungen,ch.bfe.fernwaerme-nachfrage_wohn_dienstleistungsgebaeude&layers_opacity=1,1,1,0.8,0.8,0.75&layers_visibility=false,false,false,false,false,true&layers_timestamp=18641231,,,,,&E=2746889.04&N=1258937.36&zoom=7)

For basic map creation I am using:

```
map_geo = folium.Map(location=[47.46901, 9.36688], zoom_start=13)
```

And then try to add the layer as wms layer:

```
folium.raster_layers.WmsTileLayer(url = 'https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?',
                                  layers = 'ch.bfe.fernwaerme-nachfrage_wohn_dienstleistungsgebaeude',
                                  transparent = False, 
                                  control = True, 
                                  name = 'energy',
                                  overlay=True,
                                  show = True,
                                  ).add_to(map_geo)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_geo)
```

In the end the final map looks like:
[image: map created]
If I choose the base layer alone from the layer control then I can see it. But if I activate the energy usage layer, background layer is going all white. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not know that such layers could be laid on top of each other. I went through trial and error with your code, looking at the examples in the [reference](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/WMS_and_WMTS.ipynb). To solve the problem, I formatted the image of the layer and it improved.

```
import folium

map_geo = folium.Map(location=[47.46901, 9.36688], zoom_start=13)

folium.raster_layers.WmsTileLayer(url = 'https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?',
                                  layers = 'ch.bfe.fernwaerme-nachfrage_wohn_dienstleistungsgebaeude',
                                  transparent = True, 
                                  control = True,
                                  fmt="image/png",
                                  name = 'energy',
                                  overlay = True,
                                  show = True,
                                  ).add_to(map_geo)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_geo)

map_geo
```

[image]