# Adding a WMS layer to folium

Tags: folium, streamlit, wms

I've been looking at [Adding a WMS layer using folium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992020/adding-a-wms-layer-using-folium)
and https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html.

I managed to get the example in the above link to work in streamlit but not the WMS I'm trying. I've also tried the WMS in qgis and it works.

I realized I  need to specify the coordinate system when connecting to the WMS in the below link. From what I can tell both folium and the wms supports EPSG:900913 = EPSG3857(?). However when adding the wms tile layer all i get is my base map. But the WMS isn't showing.

The WMS can be found at https://resource.sgu.se/dokument/produkter/jordarter-25-100000-wms-beskrivning.pdf
https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jordarter-25-100-tusen

```
import streamlit as st
import folium 
import streamlit_folium

    map_geo = folium.Map(location=[57.8,14.14], zoom_start=13, width=1200)
    try:
            folium.raster_layers.WmsTileLayer(url ='https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jordarter-25-100-tusen',
                            layers = ['jord:SE.GOV.SGU.JORD.TACKNINGSKARTA.25K'],
                            transparent = False, 
                            control = True,
                            fmt="image/png",
                            name = 'SGU',
                            attr = 'im seeing this',
                            overlay = True,
                            show = True,
                            CRS = 'EPSG:900913',
                            version = '1.3.0',
                            ).add_to(map_geo)
            folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_geo)
    
    except Exception as e:
            st.write(e)
    
   streamlit_folium.st_folium(map_geo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be due to the fact that the target URL and the layer designation are different. I just don't know if the called layer is the intended layer or not. I got this https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jordarter-25-100-tusen and layer from the content of the link provided.

```
import folium 

map_geo = folium.Map(location=[57.8,14.14], zoom_start=10, width=1200)

folium.raster_layers.WmsTileLayer(url ='https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/jord/ows?',
                layers = 'SE.GOV.SGU.JORD.TACKNINGSKARTA.25K',
                transparent = False, 
                control = True,
                fmt="image/png",
                name = 'SGU',
                attr = 'im seeing this',
                overlay = True,
                show = True,
                CRS = 'EPSG:900913',
                version = '1.3.0',
                ).add_to(map_geo)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(map_geo)
    
map_geo
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's the one specified in the question,  I called the rest of the available layers and got the full geological map, so it works like a charm. I did not see myself figuring this out ever, so many thanks! :)